# Joining three tables expecting results but the result is wrong

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my table:

```
user table:
id..|..fname
1...|..dan
2...|..den

trans table:
.transid.|..userid....|..adid.....|..click
.....1...|....1.......|.....1.....|.....1
.....2...|....2.......|.....1.....|.....1

ads table:
id..|..adname
1...|..sample
```

And my select clause is:

```
select u.fname, 
       t.click 
from user u 
   inner join ads a on u.id=a.id 
   inner join trans t on a.id=t.transid 
order by u.fname;
```

I was expecting a result of

```
fname....|..click
dan......|...1...
den......|...1...
```

but the result was wrong, it only shows the first line. What could be wrong here?

Comment: No relation to [Sky Scraper](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1643065/sky-scraper) from yesterday?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take care to format your questions, otherwise it just creates work for someone else - thank you.

Comment: You'll only get one row returned because you don't have an entry for den in the ads table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're simply joining the tables in the wrong order, and so on the wrong fields.

Your query...

```
select u.fname, t.click
from user u
inner join ads a on u.id=a.id
inner join trans t on a.id=t.transid
order by u.fname;
```

You join the `users` to the `ads` where the `ad` and the `user` have the same `id`.

Then you join that to the `trans` table where the `ad` shares the same `id` as the `trans`.

Neither of these make sense.

You should join the `user` to the `trans` table, which has a `userid` field.

And you should also join the `ads` to the `trans` table, which has an `adid` field.

```
SELECT
  u.fname,
  a.click
FROM
  user
INNER JOIN
  trans
    ON trans.userid = user.id
INNER JOIN
  ads
    ON ads.id = trans.adid
```

Comment: Yes, he wouldn't have had his problem if he hadn't used the antipattern of naming fields ID. Then he would have know which filed joins to which.

Comment: @HLGEM - I disagree. If using the pattern `id` rather than `<table>_id` it is ***never*** appropriate to join `ON a.id = b.id`. That covers the first mistaken join at the very least. And, to me, seeing `ON a.id t.transid` is almost as clearly a mistake. the advantage of using just `id` makes it implicit that this is the table's unique identifier (or a surrogate unique identifier) and *not* a foriegn key.  I strongly feel that this is a choice of preference / local standards.

Comment: I would suggest you read the book on SQL antipatterns then. http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356557/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1351091291&sr=1-1&keywords=sql+antipatterns

Comment: thanks sir Dems! now its making things clear to me!! thanks again sir!! :)

Answer (score 3):

this can be achieved by joining only two tables: `trans` and `user`.

```
SELECT  b.fname, a.click
FROM    trans a
        INNER JOIN user b
            ON a.userid = b.id
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6cf6b/1)

other wise if you want to access table `ads` as well join it by using `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT  b.fname, a.click, c.adname
FROM    trans a
        INNER JOIN user b
            ON a.userid = b.id
        LEFT JOIN ads c
            ON a.adid = c.id
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6cf6b/3)

Comment: @HLGEM yep, and that's normal :) simplifying for clarity (*which sometimes lead to misconception*)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the following:

```
select u.fname, t.click
from user u
left join trans t 
  on u.id=t.transid
left join ads a
  on t.adid = a.id
order by u.fname;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6bc2/11)

Comment: I don;t think ad.Id and U.id refer to the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You want to first join on the `trans` table since it has mutual relation to `user`:

```
SELECT u.fname, t.click
FROM   trans t
       INNER JOIN user u
               ON u.id = t.userid
ORDER  BY u.fname;
```

Comment: See this mess is why using ID as a name is an antipattern.